# MAC OSX El Capitan - “icCube” is damaged

Tags: osx-elcapitan, macos-high-sierra, iccube

After downloading icCube I get the following message: “icCube” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSX doesn't allow to run downloaded application by default, you've to

a) Allow just icCube application, open the application with Ctrl+Click and select open in the menu ([doc](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21769?locale=en_US)). The app will be saved as an exception in your security settings.

or a bit more brutal

b) Change your global settings in Security & Privacy to 'Anywhere' [doc](https://www.yourkit.com/download/mountain_lion.html) (bottom)

[image]

If you have **MacOS High Sierra**, the Security & Privacy window won't show the same default settings. In order to activate the "Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere", just write on your Terminal:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

and the option will be available again.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac Big Sur (Version 11.6), the 'Anywhere' option on the Security & Privacy settings is not available anymore. Instead, click on the "Open Anyway" button that will appear when launching icCube.

[image: iccube-install-mac-bigsur]

On version 13, the System Settings interface has changed but the validation button can still be found on the "Privacy & Security" settings:

[image]